# Не могу составить запрос MySQL для фильтра по товарам

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица *product (id, name)*.
Есть таблица *product_option (id, product_id, option_id)*
У продукта могут быть несколько опций, а может и не быть вообще.

Как одним запросом получить список продукции у которых есть опции (option_id), скажем: 1, 14, 25?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT p.id, p.name
  FROM product AS p
  JOIN product_option AS o
    ON p.id = o.product_id AND o.option_id in(1, 14, 25)
 GROUP BY p.id, p.name
HAVING count(1)=3
```

`3` в условии HAVING это количество условий которые должны совпасть.

Будет работать при условии, что у продукта не может быть двух одинаковых опций. Ваша структура БД этого не гарантирует, т.к. уникальность наверняка только по полю id, таблицы product_option. Рекомендую вообще убрать поле id и primary key объявить составным, из двух оставшихся колонок `primary key (option_id, product_id)`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.name
FROM
  product AS p
JOIN
  product_option AS o1
ON
  p.id = o1.product_id AND
  o1.option_id = 1
JOIN
  product_option AS o2
ON
  p.id = o2.product_id AND
  o2.option_id = 14
JOIN
  product_option AS o3
ON
  p.id = o3.product_id AND
  o3.option_id = 25
```

Comment: *option_id IN (1, 14, 25)* говорит, что подойдут все опции содержащие 1 ИЛИ 14 ИЛИ 25. Мне же нужно чтобы у продукта были как минимум 1 И 14 И 25 опции вместе. Например, если есть только 1 и 25, но нет 14 - мимо.

Comment: @GroZa поправил ответ, не особо элегантно получается, но пока более лучшего ответа не придумал. Задача интересная, спасибо.