# Как правильно сделать выборку товаров по списку параметров

Tags: postgresql

Есть данные:

```
┌──────┐                                                     
│ITEM  │                                                     
│──────│                                                     
│ id   │──┐   ┌────────────┐     ┌──────┐     ┌─────────────┐
│ name │  │   │ITEM*OPTION │     │FILTER│     │RESULT       │
└──────┘  │   │────────────│────▶│──────│────▶│─────────────│
          │   │ id         │     │ id   │     │ itemId      │
┌──────┐  └──▶│ itemId     │     │ name │     │ itemName    │
│OPTION│  ┌──▶│ optionId   │     └──────┘     └─────────────┘
│──────│  │   └────────────┘                                 
│ id   │──┘                                                  
│ name │                                                     
└──────┘
```

нужно согласно фильтра опций отобрать товары

пока на ум приходит вложенные SELECT, есть способ проще?

Так работает:

```
SELECT *
FROM `item`
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT `itemId` FROM `itemOption` WHERE `itemOption`.`optionId` = "e9c465f0-3e7f-11e6-b790-d97fec0abca2") as `o0`
  ON `item`.`id`= `o0`.`itemId`
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT `itemId` FROM `itemOption` WHERE `itemOption`.`optionId` = "1a8f4c40-4204-11e6-9617-b134f2c891f2") as `o1`
  ON `item`.`id`= `o1`.`itemId`
```

Comment: Пока не очень понятно, как таблица FILTER связана с ITEM и OPTION. Обычно способа два, либо вложенные запросы, либо JOIN-ы.

Comment: FILTER - список опций выбранных пользователем, 
RESULT - список ITEMS отвечающих критериям фильтра

Comment: У вас в FILTER только id и некий name как проверить что данный ITEM подходит под данный FILTER. У них равны name, или может name из OPTION или какие нибудь id равны ? И если задано несколько FILTER то удовлетворяющим условию считаются ITEM у которых подошло хотя бы одно из условий или все условия ?

Comment: И вам что нибудь типа этого http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518991/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-mysql-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC/518999#518999 не подойдет ? (только вместо IN добавление таблицы filter в join)

Comment: Так работает:

SELECT *
FROM `item`
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT `itemID` FROM `itemOption` WHERE `itemOption`.`optionId` = "e9c465f0-3e7f-11e6-b790-d97fec0abca2") as `o0`
  ON `item`.`id`= `o0`.`itemID`
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT `itemID` FROM `itemOption` WHERE `itemOption`.`optionId` = "1a8f4c40-4204-11e6-9617-b134f2c891f2") as `o1`
  ON `item`.`id`= `o1`.`itemID`


Хотелось сделать проще.

форматирование в комментариях победить не смог...

Comment: @AlexSuslov А где в вашем запросе таблица FILTER. И ваш пример один к одному как в том ответе, ссылку на который я привел выше. Вот там в ответе проверяется наличие трех конкретных опций и делает это за одну склейку с таблицей опций

Comment: FILTER это у меня не таблица а список, 
"JOIN" я добавляю итератором. 
Согласен ссылка на этот же способ.

Comment: @AlexSuslov Тогда я правильно понимаю, что тот ответ полностью отвечает на ваш вопрос ?

Comment: @AlexSuslov Короче вот адаптация того ответа `SELECT item.*
FROM item
INNER JOIN itemOption ON item.id=itemOption.itemId and
 optionId in("e9c465f0-3e7f-11e6-b790-d97fec0abca2", "1a8f4c40-4204-11e6-9617-b134f2c891f2")
GROUP BY item.id
HAVING count(1)=2
` И вопрос думаю можно закрывать

Comment: Этот запрос выдает множество(работает как "или")