# Как задать сложное условие по связаной таблице

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть 2 таблицы User , Book , связь один ко многим, т.е у пользователя может быть много книг.

*Book

- user_id
- book_id

Со структуры таблицы видно что связь типа many_many, но это не столь важно.
К примеру мне нужно выбрать пользователей которые прочли книги с ИД 1 и 2.

```
Такой запрос не работает
"SELECT * FROM user LEFT JOIN book ON user.id = book.user_id WHERE book.book_id = 1 AND book.book_id = 2 ";
```

Comment: И что именно не получается?

Comment: LEFT не нужен. Он был бы нужен если бы вас интересовали _все_ пользователи и у _некоторых_ надо было бы показать еще и требуемые книги. А условие `book.book_id = 1 AND book.book_id = 2` всегда ложно. Не может у одной записи быть `id=1 И-одновременно id=2`. Было бы правильно `book.book_id = 1 OR book.book_id = 2`, что в короткой записи выглядит `book.book_id IN(1,2)`

Comment: @Mike - `book.book_id = 1 AND book.book_id = 2` - я понимаю что это условие ложно, но как верно составить запрос не знаю

Comment: @Mike - Вроде довольно внятно написано что я хочу получить в результате: `нужно выбрать пользователей которые прочли книги с ИД 1 и 2`. Если поставить OR - это не даст нужный результат.

Comment: @Mike , http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518991/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-mysql-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC/518999#518999 - то что нужно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Зачем вам LEFT JOIN?

2) в одной строчке выборки условие: `book.book_id = 1 AND book.book_id = 2` - всегда даст ложь, поскольку book_id не может одновременно быть равным 1 и 2 :):)

Вам поможет примерно следующий запрос, например:

```
SELECT user.id 
FROM user 
  INNER JOIN book ON user.id = book.user_id 
GROUP BY user.id
HAVING 
  MAX(IF(book.book_id = 1, 1, 0)) = 1
  AND
  MAX(IF(book.book_id = 2, 1, 0)) = 1
```

Оба условия в HAVING означают, что в группе есть хотя бы одно значение book_id, которое мы задали.
Т.е. именно то, что вам нужно.

**UPD:** По совету Mike:

```
SELECT user.id 
FROM user 
  INNER JOIN book ON user.id = book.user_id 
WHERE book.book_i IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY user.id
HAVING COUNT(*)=2
```

Comment: Логику понял, сейчас попробую составить criteria в yii

Comment: @Mike, можете объяснить что значит это выражение `count(1)=2`

Comment: @РоманМальцев То же, что и `count(*)=2`. До группировки запрос выберет для каждого пользователя столько записей, сколько книг с указанными ID у них окажется. Так как в условии поиска 2 книги, то если у пользователя 2 книги с ID 1 и 2 то будет получено 2 записи и count(*) даст 2

Comment: @РоманМальцев, функция count(X) считает количество значений X в группе отличных от NULL. Таким образом, COUNT(1), COUNT('some string const') - вернут просто количество строк. В стандарте языка принято обозначение COUNT(*) - т.е. просто количество строк в группе.