# Не могу написать правильный SQL запрос

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Уже третий час ломаю голову как написать правильный запрос, но ничего не выходит.
 
Задача такая:
Есть таблица автомобилей

```
auto (автомобили)
id | name
-------------
1  | Volvo
2  | Audi
3  | Toyota
```

Есть таблица запчастей

```
spare (запчасти)
id | name
-------------
1  | Колеса
2  | Двигатель
3  | Руль
```

Есть many to many таблица для соединение запчастей и автомобилей

```
spare_to_auto
auto_id | spare_id
------------------
1       | 1
1       | 2
1       | 3
2       | 1
2       | 2
```

Нужно получить все автомобили у которых список запчастей в spare_to_auto полностью совпадает.
Список запчастей задает пользователь в фильтре. Например если пользователь задал в фильтре, запчасти 1 и 2 то запрос должен вернуть автомобили 1 и 2 т.к. у этих двух автомобилей обе эти запчасти - есть.

Вот что у меня получилось в итоге

```
SELECT * 
FROM auto as a
INNER JOIN spare_to_auto AS s_to_a
ON a.id = s_to_a.auto_id
INNER JOIN spare AS s
ON s_to_a.spare_id = s.id AND s.id IN ($список_запчастей)
```

Но к сожаление работает это запрос не правильно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу составить запрос MySQL для фильтра по товарам](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518991/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-mysql-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select auto.name 
from auto, spare_to_auto as s2a1, spare_to_auto as s2a2
where 
auto.auto_id = s2a1.auto_id and 
auto.auto_id = s2a2.auto_id and 
s2a1.spare_id = 1
s2a2.spare_id = 2
order by auto.name
```

Синонимов spare_to_auto (и соответственно условий на них) будет столько, сколько элементов в списке фильтров spare_id