# Не могу написать SQL запрос

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Уже третий час ломаю голову как написать правильный запрос, но ничего не выходит.
 
Задача такая:
Есть таблица автомобилей

```
auto (автомобили)
id | name
-------------
1  | Volvo
2  | Audi
3  | Toyota
```

Есть таблица запчастей

```
spare (запчасти)
id | name
-------------
1  | Колеса
2  | Двигатель
3  | Руль
```

Есть many to many таблица для соединение запчастей и автомобилей

```
spare_to_auto
auto_id | spare_id
------------------
1       | 1
1       | 2
1       | 3
2       | 1
2       | 2
```

Нужно получить список автомобилей у которых список запчастей совпадает от двух и более. И еще их нужно отсортировать в порядке совпадения от большего к меньшему. Список запчастей задает пользователь в фильтре

Вот что у меня получилось в итоге

```
SELECT * 
FROM auto as a
INNER JOIN spare_to_auto AS s_to_a
ON a.id = s_to_a.auto_id
INNER JOIN spare AS s
ON s_to_a.spare_id = s.id AND s.id IN ($список_запчастей)
GROUP BY a.id
```

Но к сожаление работает это запрос не правильно.

Comment: Чем этот вопрос отличается от [этого](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/635524)?

Comment: Там нужно получить список автомобилей у которых общие детали полностью совпадают. А здесь частично

Comment: Причем в том вопросе вы приняли не самый хороший ответ, он конечно рабочий, но тот что я там же указал как дубль лучше т.к. позволяет не клеить таблицу много раз и главное, он если убрать условие having и добавить `order by count(1)  desc` как раз дает сортировку по количеству совпадений. так что к тому что вы написали тут остается только такой order by добавить и все

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM auto as a
 INNER JOIN spare_to_auto AS s_to_a ON a.id = s_to_a.auto_id
 WHERE s_to_a.spare_id IN ($список_запчастей)
 GROUP BY a.id
HAVING count(1)>1
 ORDER BY count(1) desc
```

Таблицу `spare` из запроса я убрал, так как выборка идет по ID запчастей, которые и так уже есть в `spare_to_auto`. Кстати, поиск всех запчастей отличается только изменением условия в having на равенство количеству искомых.

Answer (score 1):

```
select name from auto as a
inner join (
  select i1.auto_id,count(1) as count from spare_to_auto as i1 
  inner join spare_to_auto as i2 on i1.spare_id=i2.spare_id 
  and i1.auto_id<>i2.auto_id
  group by i1.auto_id) as b
on a.id=b.auto_id and b.count>1
```

Comment: Дополните ваш ответ детальным описанием решения проблемы или описанием кода, чтобы пользователям было легче понять ваш ответ.