# Как правильно сформировать вывода SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Здравствуйте.

Есть таблица MYSQL в базе с колонками

```
server_id   |    game_mod     |   version_ms
------------+-----------------+-------------
  1         | 5,7,8,9,10,15   |     1.9
  2         | 7,55,99,20,1    |     2.2
  3         | 1,2,3,4,5,8,9   |     3.0
```

Данные в колонке game_mod хранятся через запятую

Мне надо вывести из таблицы сервера к примеру только с двумя модами, но у сервера много модов. 
Просто LIKE % % не подходит.

Суть в том что у каждого сервера есть куда модов и названия модов хранятся в другой таблице, сюда просто id прописываются этих модов. Вот я не знаю как сделать поиск по выбраным модам.

Помогите пожалуйста, может даже другой реализацией. Колонку для каждого мода добавлять безумство, так как модов больше 100

**В общем нужно составить запрос, чтобы вывести все сервера с модами 1 и 9**

Спасибо большое тем кто поможет!

Comment: нет не безумство, а правильное решение. У вас бы не было таких проблем. База данных на то и нужна, чтобы хранить данные. Безумство хранить ID, которые нужны для связки текстом через запятую

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0

Answer (score 1):

Почему `LIKE '%...%'` не подходит? Рассмотрим для каждой цифры 3 случая - цифра в начале, в середине и в конце.

```
select server_id, game_mod
from servers
where (game_mod like '1,%' or game_mod like '%,1,%' or game_mod like '%,1')
    and (game_mod like '9,%' or game_mod like '%,9,%' or game_mod like '%,9')
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас нехорошая архитектура базы. Даже если сейчас вы решите ваш вопрос с помощью LIKE, то потом вы всё равно будете огребать всё новые и новые проблемы.

Правильно делать три таблицы:

В первой у вас будут сервера и колонок только две - server_id и version_ms.

Во второй - моды, с колонками mod_id и название мода.

А вот третья таблица (связующая) и делает всю магию. В ней две колонки - server_id и mod_id. В этой таблице для каждого сервера будет столько строк, сколько на этом сервере модов.

Более подробно вы можете нагуглить по запросам "нормализация баз данных" и "отношение многие-ко-многим".

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я уже тоже подумал об этом. А вы можете составить запрос для трех таблиц если выбираем 2 мода

Comment: @Денис что то в этом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518991/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-mysql-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC/518999#518999 роде. и третья таблица в запросе понадобится только если эти самые имена модов надо будет подтягивать. А так как основная задача получить сервера то третья таблица в данном запросе ну нужна будет