# Как составить SQL Запрос для фильтрации по трем таблицам?

Tags: mysql, sql

В общем есть 3 таблицы
1 - `servers` (server_id, server_name,version_ms );
2 - `mod_name` (mod_id, mod_name );
3 - `server_mod` (m_servid, m_modid );

1.есть таблица серверов с названием сервера
2. Есть таблица с названием модов для серверов
3. Есть таблица где только ид мода и ид сервера (из первых двух таблица)

У сервера может быть 10-20 модов разных

**Помогите составить  запрос для поиска**,  мне надо показать все сервера у которых есть  пару модов, к примеру ид модов 5 и 10.

Прочитал JOIN, но так и не смог составить.
Вот что получилось
`SELECT serv.server_id , serv.server_name, modserv.m_modid as mod_id FROM`servers`serv LEFT OUTER JOIN`server_mod`modserv ON modserv.m_modid=9 WHERE`version_ms`='1.8'`

Не корректно работает запрос, модов может быть много, а версия всегда одна

Спасибо большое за ответы

Comment: В условиях JOIN практически всегда участвуют колонки из двух таблиц. Той которую присоединяют и той к которой присоединяют. Сейчас у вас каждая запись modserv с указанными условиями выборки присоединяется к каждой записи двух других таблиц. И я вам давал уже ссылку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518991/518999#518999 там примерно ваш случай.

Comment: И посмотрите внимательно все вопросы по SQL за сегодня. Ваш вопрос уже третий за день на подобную тему !

Comment: И кстати, что вы хотите получить в результате запроса. В начале вы пишите что вам нужны сервера. Такая постановка вопроса подразумевает, что вы видимо хотите получить по одной строке на каждый сервер. Но в вашем запросе на выводе присутствует m_modid, что должно быть в этом поле, если по серверу найдутся два разных мода ? запрос должен либо вывести две строки с одним и тем же сервером с каждым модом, либо не выводить это поле (ну либо в нем например список собираемый group_concat)

Comment: Я пробывал, но ничего не получилось SELECT serv.server_id,serv.server_ip, serv.server_port, serv.server_name , serv.version_ms, modserv.mod_modid
  FROM `amx_servers` AS serv
  JOIN `amx_mod_server` AS modserv
    ON serv.server_id=modserv.mod_modid AND modserv.mod_modid in(8,9,10)
GROUP BY serv.server_id, serv.server_name
HAVING count(1)=3

Comment: Надо получить к примеру все сервера с модом.ид=10

Comment: Если модом id=10 то вот и пишите в том IN только 10 и count(1)=1 так как условие только одно. правда когда он один то тут и group by не нужен и having. когда условие одно оно и так сработает. когда больше - тогда вот и нужен group by и having. И что значит "не получилось" - выдает какую то ошибку или просто результат 0 строк ? Если второе - то вы уверены что у вас в БД есть записи с модами 8,9,10 ?