# Поиск массива чисел в нескольких строках MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, yii2, group-by, relation

Имеется таблица p_links_requirements (Связана с другими таблицами по индексам).
Пример запроса:
SELECT * FROM p_links_requirements lr WHERE lr.requirement_id = 1

```
id |link_id|requirement_id| value   
64 |   1   |      1       |   0
65 |   1   |      1       |   2
```

Есть некий набор массивов чисел **();(0);(2);(0,2);(0,1,2)** - массив для поиска значений **value**. Вся соль в том, что я должен получить link_id, в котором из выборки сверху присутствует хотя бы одно из массива и нет несуществующих!

Т.е. при **();(0);(2);(0,2)** я должен получить запись с link_id = 1.

При **(0,1,2)** - ответ должен быть пустым

Что нужно писать до *GROUP BY link_id*

Comment: ну в общем виде запрос должен выглядеть как то так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518991/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-mysql-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC/518999#518999