# сгруппировать столбец в массив Postgresql

Tags: sql, массивы, postgresql

Цитата

есть таблица id_m (int), id_t (int) которая обеспечивает связь многие-ко-многим. Нужно выбрать id_m у которых id_t полностью пересекаются с заданными в запросе.
например:

```
 id_m | id_t
-------------
    1 |    1
    1 |    2
    3 |    1
```

в ответ должен попасть id_m=1 при запросе id_t = {1,2} (и не попасть id_m=3, потому что у него нет id_t=2)
Как это лучше сделать? сначала подумал можно сделать таблицу 
id_m | array(id_t) as t а потом сравнить два массива - t и {1,2}
Но тут вопрос - как составить запрос, который бы собрал соответствующие id_t в массив. или может какой-то более элегантный способ

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу составить запрос MySQL для фильтра по товарам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518991/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-mysql-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id_m from some_m2m group by id_m having array_agg(id_t) = '{1, 2}';
```