# Как создать умный запрос?

Tags: php, mysql

Возникла проблема: есть чекбоксы с именами, отвечающими за id жанра(условно).Мне нужно, что-бы пользователь выбирал, игры с каким жанрами ему нужны, и они ему показывались на экране.Как это сделал я:
Пользователь тыкает на чекбоксы, потом "Отправить", после чего срабатывает код.Там есть переменная, которая берет все жанры из таблицы, потом foreach, где прописано вот что:

```
$getGenres = Переменная, берущая все жанры из таблицы.
$data = $_GET(Все данные о чекбоксах отправляются по этому методу)
foreach($getGenres as $t){ 
if($data[$t['id']] == 'on'){ 
//code
} 
}
```

Только проблема в том, что данный метод может сработать, если выбрать определенный жанр.Да, я могу Все жанры записать в массив:

```
$Variable = array():
foreach($getGenres as $t){ 
if($data[$t['id']] == 'on'){ 
$Variable[] = $data[$t['id']];
} 
}
```

Тогда у меня будут все id жанров, которые выбрал пользователь.Но как мне сконструировать запрос?Ведь, изначально, мы не знаем, сколько всего жанров есть.Можно посчитать кол-во значений в массиве, допустим, юзер выбрал 3 жанра, значит в массиве 3 значения с информацией.Тогда будет запрос примерно такой:

```
SELECT * FROM таблица WHERE id = 1 AND id = 3 AND id=2(Значения условны)
```

Но если юзер выберет сразу 4 жанра?А пять?
А теперь к сути: Как сделать умный запрос, который будет получать информацию независимо от того, сколько нужно сделать условий.
Запрос должен выглядеть примерно так(Он неправильный, проверял):

```
SELECT * FROM `genres` WHERE id = 1,2,3(идам из массива(Выбранные пользователем))
```

Comment: Информации не достаточно. Какова структура таблицы с жанрами в БД. запрос в том виде как вы привели `where id=1 and id=2` не может вернуть ни одной строки, так как условие действует для каждой записи отдельно, а id не может быть одновременно равен и 1 и 2. Обычно в таком случае используется таблица в которой лежат 2 поля id-фильма и id-жанра. т.е. для каждого жанра отдельная запись, в таких случаях обычный подход выбор с условием OR (или точнее IN, что бы перечислить все значения) и подсчет подошедших строк в разрезе id фильма, что то вроде этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518999/194569

Answer (score 1):

Может быть

```
if(!empty($getGenres)){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `genres` WHERE id IN ('.join(',',$getGenres).')';
}
```

Ну и понятно, перед встраиванием в sql, массив $getGenres хорошо бы проверить на пользовательский ввод