# Как выбрать записи где значение dialog_id совпадает зная только user_id обеих пользователей

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

Помогите выбрать диалог по пользователях. 
К примеру есть значения:

```
первый user_id = 1, второй user_id = 2.
```

[image: db example]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/518991/194569

Comment: @Mike  Не подходит, так как нет значения dialog_id

Comment: *Не подходит* Вы не разобрались в ответе по ссылке. Прекрасно подходит... `dialog_id` - это не входные данные, а возвращаемый запросом параметр.

Comment: @Akina не разобрался, помогите сформировать запрос

Comment: Отбирайте по списку user_id, группируйте по dialog_id, и оставляйте то, для чего COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) равен двум.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
SELECT u.dialog_id FROM users u1
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u2.dialog_id = u.dialog_id
WHERE u.user_id = 1 AND u2.user_id = 2 AND u2.dialog_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Этот запрос позволяет допустить более 2-х пользователей в результате.

Comment: Этого условия не было в вопросе.

    SELECT dialog_id FROM users WHERE 1 GROUP BY dialog_id HAVING COUNT(user_id) = 2 AND user_id IN (1,2)

Comment: Это условие возвращает ошибку.

Comment: Какого рода ошибка ? Ошибок нет. Проверено на MySQL 5.7

Comment: Unknown column 'user_id' in 'having clause'

Запрос: SELECT dialog_id FROM dialog_member WHERE 1 GROUP BY dialog_id HAVING COUNT(user_id) = 2 AND user_id IN (1,2)

Comment: Попробуйте добавить user_id в выборку. Возможно это как-то связано с версией базы данных.SELECT dialog_id, user_id FROM users WHERE 1 GROUP BY dialog_id HAVING COUNT(user_id) = 2 AND user_id IN (1,2)