# какой придумать SQL запрос

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть вот такая табличка. Нужно придумать запрос, при котором "пользователь" вводит ингредиенты, и получает номер рецептов на которые есть ингредиенты (кол-во в данный момент не играет роли).

[image: Таблица]

Comment: Чтобы вам помогли, выложите код который вы вымучали за неделю. Плюс не хватает данных. Где вводит? Куда выводится? Динамически или с перезагрузкой? И так далее..

Comment: Там нет ничего толкового. Много попыток использовать like. В итоге получается искать рецепты, которые точно соответствуют введенным ингредиентам.

Comment: на каком языке программирования пишите?

Comment: @doox911 Где вводится и куда выводится не играет никакой роли. Нужно придумать саму логику запроса, а в нужный код я и сам встроить могу.

Comment: @Arendach на Java

Comment: Логика такова: Вам надо создать набор из этих значений. Дать пользователю выбрать сначала элемент один (массив предопределённых значений) а затем дать доступ к второму аналогичному элементу. После взять значения выбранных элементов и запросить их по полям ingridient и quantiti через оператор =.

Comment: @doox911 не до конца понял. Можете примерно показать как это будет выглядеть, а то я в SQL новичок

Comment: @ТимофейПопов select id form "ваша таблица" where ingredient=field1 AND quantity=field2. field 1 и 2 - это ваши значения из элементов.

Comment: Могу подробнее расписать на php + html в ответе. Если данная логика вас устраивает.

Comment: А что такое "рецепт на который есть ингредиенты" ? Это в котором есть все перечисленные. Или хотя бы часть перечисленных. Или все перечисленные и никаких более ? Что то мне подсказывает что вам нужна вариация на тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/518991/194569

Comment: @Mike "рецепт на который есть ингредиенты" - это такой рецепт, который ты можешь сделать в данный момент ничего не покупая дополнительно, при этом использовать все ингредиенты не обязательно.

Comment: Вам нужно пересмотреть архитектуру, иначе это будет безбожно тормозить. 1 Таблица ингридиенты(id, name, {опционально мера измерения, шт\гр\..}), вторая таблица (recepie_id,ingridient_id,count), тогда в 2 запроса можно будет выбрать все подходящие рецепты и рецепты которые возможно бы подошли, но в любом случае это очень большая нагрузка на БД будет.

Comment: То изменение которое я предлагаю сделать нужно в связи использованием group_concat и find_in_set что на длинных строках начнет тормозить(вместо вашего текста будут соединятся по индексам).

Comment: А вы табличку специально в виде картинки привели, что бы перед ответом надо было полчаса потратить на ввод контрольного примера ?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Дело в том, что не удается придумать сам запрос. Оптимизация еще не затрагивалась вообще

Answer (score 3):

```
select Recipie_ID
  from Table
 group by Recipie_ID
having count(1) = sum(ingredient in('Яйцо куриное', 'Мука пшеничная', ...))
```

Берет те рецепты в которых общее количество ингредиентов точно равно количеству ингредиентов совпавших со списком. Но при этом наличие в рецепте всех ингредиентов из списка не обязательно. Если надо искать на точное соответствие то надо проверять count(1) на равенству размера заданного списка.

Если надо учитывать еще и количества ингредиентов, то в sum() надо будет писать более сложные условия вроде `(ingredient='Яйцо' and quantity <= 5) OR (igreditent=X and quantity <= Y)`. Набор условий после совпадения дает 1, при не совпадении 0, собственно эти 0 и 1 и считает sum(). И конечно в БД надо все держать в предопределенных единицах измерения. Сравнивать "1/4 стакана" с "50 мл" не представляется возможным.

Comment: Красивое решение =) но одна вещь не учитывается, хотя это уже можно отсеять на стороне программы а не базы(я про кол-во ингридиентов(2 яйца или 100г сахара))

Comment: Выглядит логично, но почему то это не работает

Comment: Все заработало, я понял в чем косяк. Нужно чтобы соль и все такое подразумевалось заранее.