# Запрос по логическому выражению

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Нужно реализовать поиск некоей сущности по наличию у неё определенных меток. При этом, использовать логическое выражение по типу *"И метка1 И метка2 ИЛИ метка3"*.

На данный момент, поиск работает только по логике "И", следующим образом(`v_tags` это просто коллекция айдишников меток):

```
if v_filter_tags > 0 then
v_sql := v_sql || ' and e.tag_ids is not null and exists (
select 1
from ext_document_tag edt
where edt.ext_document_id = e.ext_document_id 
      and edt.tag_id in (select /*+cardinality(vt,1)*/ column_value from table(v_tags) vt))';
  end if;
```

Моя идея заключалась в том, чтобы на стороне клиента сделать табличку с метками и комбобоксом, который бы выбирал логическое значение для каждой из меток. И отправлять строку вида *"And-2;Or-8;"*, которую потом парсить в табличку из двух колонок и в цикле генерировать часть динамического запроса:

```
for a in 1..v_tags.count --v_tags это табличка из двух колонок(логическое значение и айдишника)
 loop
   if v_tags(a).n = 'Or' then
     v_sql := v_sql || 'and exists ( select 1 from ext_document_tag edt 
                        where edt.ext_document_id = e.ext_document_id and edt.tag_id not in ('||v_tags(a).i||')) ';
                        
   elsif v_tags(a).n = 'And' then
      v_sql := v_sql || 'and exists ( select 1 from ext_document_tag edt 
                        where edt.ext_document_id = e.ext_document_id and edt.tag_id in ('||v_tags(a).i||')) ';
   end if;
 end loop;
```

Но здесь есть непонимание. Подобный запрос, как я понимаю, не особо оптимален. И, в случае, если потребуется логика с скобочками - это уже не сработает.

Посоветуйте, как быть в данной ситуации?

Comment: мне кажется это не C#.

Comment: @Alias спасибо, поправил

Comment: Первый запрос на логику "И" совершенно не похож. Он же даст истину если найдет хотя бы один из тегов в v_tags. А "И" подразумевает, что все перечисленные теги присутствуют, а значит ожидается group by и having count

Comment: @Mike А в каком ключе подразумевается использование group by и having count?

Comment: @JohnGrave https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518999/194569

Comment: уточнили бы вы вопрос все таки. "И метка1 И метка2 ИЛИ метка3" - какой в результате должен быть запрос? т.е. по идее это означает, что нужно найти все документы с меткой3 либо все документы для которых включены обе метки метка1 и метка2... такой вы видите результат? по вашему коду выходит: если And, то вы получите все документы где есть хотя бы одна из перечисленных меток, а если OR, то все документы, где ни одна из меток не привязана, т.е. если хотя бы одна из меток к документу привязана, то этот документ вы не получите.

Comment: по поводу оптимальности, вам лучше смотреть в сторону [EXECUTE IMMIDIATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm) или в сторону [dbms_sql](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Динамический SQL нужен только в случае, если имена идентиферов БД заранее не известны. Для динамически изменяемых условий он необязателен.

Предложу вопользоваться двумерным массивом значений. По горизонтали - список допустимых значений (ИЛИ), по вертикали - список условий (И). Небольшой вспомогательной функцией проверять массив всех тегов документа на совпадение.

```
create or replace type tagList is table of varchar2 (8)
/
create or replace type tagCond is table of tagList
/
create or replace function matchTags (tags tagList, cons tagCond) return char as 
    matches int := 0;
begin 
    <<foreachcond>> for ci in 1..cons.count loop
        <<foreachtag>> for ti in 1..tags.count loop
            if tags(ti) member of cons(ci) then
                matches := matches + 1;
                continue foreachcond;
            end if; 
        end loop;
    end loop;
    return case when matches = cons.count then 'y' else 'n' end;
end;
/
create table tags (docid number, tag varchar2 (8)); 
insert into tags 
    select 1, 'tag11' from dual union all 
    select 1, 'tag12' from dual union all 
    select 1, 'tag13' from dual union all 
    select 1, 'tag99' from dual;
```

Допустим, для тегов в тестовых данных надо проверить следующее условие совпадения:

```
tag11 AND tag12 AND tag13 AND (tag14 OR tag15) OR tag99
```

Вызов и результат:

```
select docid, matchTags (
    cast (collect (tag) as tagList), 
    tagCond (
        tagList ('tag11', 'tag99'), 
        tagList ('tag12', 'tag99'),
        tagList ('tag13', 'tag99'),
        tagList ('tag14', 'tag15', 'tag99'))) matched 
from tags
group by docid
/

     DOCID MATCHED 
---------- --------
         1 y
```