# Как сделать поиск значения по ID

Tags: php, sql

Пример:

Есть таблица `posts`, в нем поле `categories`, где значения через запятую `1,2,5,15,16,22,32`

```
$search = 5;
// или $search = "1,15";
```

Как составить `SQL` запрос на `PHP` где поле `categories` соответствует переменной `$search` ?

Comment: *поле categories, где значения через запятую 1,2,5,15,16,22,32* - нормализуйте данные. *$search = "1,15"* С показанными структурой и критерием реляционное деление на SQL будет достаточно сложным.

Comment: @Akina, пытаюсь просто вывести посты нужной категории по `ID`. Может как то нужно изменить таблицу?

Comment: Типичная M:N связь. Вместо CSV должна быть отдельная таблица `(post_id, category_id)`.

Comment: @Akina, пробовал такой запрос, но срабатывает почему то не корректно `mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE categories LIKE '%$search%'");` но уже не работает если такое значение `"1,15"`

Comment: Запрос идеологически неверен. Поиск "сеткой" (искать список в списке) не существует в принципе. Кстати, на показанном значении будет найдено, например, `$search='2,3'` (*1,2,5,15,16,2**2,3**2*), что вряд ли правильно.

Comment: @SergeyMironov Вот пример правильного поиска https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518999/194569 и там же в самом вопросе написана правильная для SQL структура данных. Там 2 таблицы, в вашем случае в posts все кроме категорий, а категории в отдельной таблице с 2 полями id-поста и id-категории.

Answer (score 1):

Если не менять структуру БД, можно сделать примерно так:

```php
<?php

$search = "1,15";
$ids = explode(",", $search);
$where = [];
foreach($ids as $id) {
    $where[] = "CONCAT(',', categories, ',') LIKE '%,$id,%'";
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $where);
```

Но этот вариант будет очень тяжелым для выполнения. Лучше нормализовать базу данных, добавить внешние ключи, индексы и использовать `JOIN`